# When i install a new version of python i need to install the packages again

Tags: python-3.x, pip

When i install (upgrade) to the new version of Python (3.8.1 in this case) i need to install the packages again such as:

- requests
- pandas
- sklearn
- matplotlib

etc...

(i have to do `pip install moduleName` for each one).

This is not the first time such has happenned.

How does one execute the installation of a new version without having to re-install the packages ?

Comment: Upgraded to the new version of Python — from which one?

Comment: To prepare for such cases (and many others), it's always a good habit to curate a list of dependencies in form of a [`requirements.txt`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#requirements-files) file for example. It makes reinstalling all these dependencies a very easy operation.

Comment: moving from version 3.7 to 3.8, but i have also had the same for previous versions. Does not seem right that a user has to re-install packages following an upgrade.

Comment: @D.L The installed projects are quite tightly coupled to the version of the Python interpreter indeed. When moving between maintenance versions (example 3.7.0 to 3.7.5, or 3.8.0 to 3.8.1), there is usually no need to reinstall the project dependencies. But moving between major or minor versions (for example, 2.x to 3.x or 3.6.x to 3.8.x), project dependencies have to be reinstalled. Anyway thanks to _pip_'s caching, _pip_'s  _requirements_ files, _virtual environments_, and other tools, reinstalling all the dependencies should be a close to 100% worry-free operation.

Answer (score 1):

Before you upgrade in a terminal run,

`pip freeze > requirements.txt`

This will store the names and versions of all your downloaded modules in a requirements.txt file in the current directory. Then after your new version of python is downloaded cd back into that directory and run

`pip install -r requirements.txt`

This will re-install all of your modules without having to enter them in one by one.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question "*How does one execute the installation of a new version without having to re-install the packages ?*"

Comment: The re-installation would still create dupicate files (of the same packages) on the computers drive. Trying to avoid this....